# iCarousel not setting label in it properly

Tags: ios, icarousel

In my code i was trying to set label in iCarouselView.My icarousel contains labels and textView so i am trying to set label but it is not setting properly.I have array of months and setting that array of months to each icarousel label, like this.

> ```
>      (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
>     {
>        if (!view)
>    {
>          UIViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopUpView"];
>     view = [viewController.view viewWithTag:999];
>      UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[viewController.view viewWithTag:109];
>    label.text = [_monthsArray objectAtIndex:index];
>    CGRect  Frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y+100, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
>     view.frame = Frame;
> }
> return view;}
> ```

I am loading external view as popUpView in storyBoard and getting label using tag.
And i am returning carousel count as [monthsArray count].
carousel delegate and datasource is also set and reloadData method is also called on iCarousel.

The output which i am getting is something like this.

| January,February,March,November,December|

Please tell me where i am wrong?and what to do now?

Comment: iCaurosel delegate will take a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you code to below one -

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view){
        UIViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopUpView"];
        view = [viewController.view viewWithTag:999];
        CGRect  Frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y+100, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        view.frame = Frame;
    }

    UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:109];
    label.text = [_monthsArray objectAtIndex:index];

    return view;
}
```

iCaurosel will take UIView, In your case you are creating a view controller, which is not retained and is dangerous. See if you change it to view via a custom Xib.